# How to count states using case statement

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am converting a column of state abbreviations to state names but I'd also like to get a count of each state name. When I try adding `SELECT state,count(*) as count` to the beginning of my query, I end up getting errors. Where can I add a count function to get an output with state names and count of each?

Code I'm using

```
query = """
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN state = 'AL' THEN 'Alabama'
    WHEN state = 'AK' THEN 'Alaska' 
    WHEN state = 'AZ' THEN 'Arizona' 
    WHEN state = 'AR' THEN 'Arkansas' 
    WHEN state = 'CA' THEN 'California' 
    WHEN state = 'CO' THEN 'Colorado' 
    WHEN state = 'CT' THEN 'Connecticut' 
    WHEN state = 'DE' THEN 'Delaware' 
    WHEN state = 'DC' THEN 'District of Columbia' 
    WHEN state = 'FL' THEN 'Florida' 
    WHEN state = 'GA' THEN 'Georgia' 
    WHEN state = 'HI' THEN 'Hawaii' 
    WHEN state = 'ID' THEN 'Idaho' 
    WHEN state = 'IL' THEN 'Illinois' 
    WHEN state = 'IN' THEN 'Indiana' 
    WHEN state = 'IA' THEN 'Iowa' 
    WHEN state = 'KS' THEN 'Kansas' 
    WHEN state = 'KY' THEN 'Kentucky' 
    WHEN state = 'LA' THEN 'Louisiana' 
    WHEN state = 'ME' THEN 'Maine' 
    WHEN state = 'MD' THEN 'Maryland' 
    WHEN state = 'MA' THEN 'Massachusetts' 
    WHEN state = 'MI' THEN 'Michigan' 
    WHEN state = 'MN' THEN 'Minnesota' 
    WHEN state = 'MS' THEN 'Mississippi' 
    WHEN state = 'MO' THEN 'Missouri' 
    WHEN state = 'MT' THEN 'Montana' 
    WHEN state = 'NE' THEN 'Nebraska' 
    WHEN state = 'NV' THEN 'Nevada' 
    WHEN state = 'NH' THEN 'New Hampshire' 
    WHEN state = 'NJ' THEN 'New Jersey' 
    WHEN state = 'NM' THEN 'New Mexico' 
    WHEN state = 'NY' THEN 'New York' 
    WHEN state = 'NC' THEN 'North Carolina' 
    WHEN state = 'ND' THEN 'North Dakota' 
    WHEN state = 'OH' THEN 'Ohio' 
    WHEN state = 'OK' THEN 'Oklahoma' 
    WHEN state = 'OR' THEN 'Oregon' 
    WHEN state = 'PA' THEN 'Pennsylvania' 
    WHEN state = 'RI' THEN 'Rhode Island' 
    WHEN state = 'SC' THEN 'South Carolina' 
    WHEN state = 'SD' THEN 'South Dakota' 
    WHEN state = 'TN' THEN 'Tennessee' 
    WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas' 
    WHEN state = 'UT' THEN 'Utah' 
    WHEN state = 'VT' THEN 'Vermont' 
    WHEN state = 'VA' THEN 'Virginia' 
    WHEN state = 'WA' THEN 'Washington' 
    WHEN state = 'WV' THEN 'West Virginia' 
    WHEN state = 'WI' THEN 'Wisconsin' 
    WHEN state = 'WY' THEN 'Wyoming' 
    WHEN state = 'AB' THEN 'Alberta' 
    WHEN state = 'BC' THEN 'British Columbia' 
    WHEN state = 'MB' THEN 'Manitoba' 
    WHEN state = 'NM' THEN 'New Brunswick' 
    WHEN state = 'NL' THEN 'Newfoundland and Labrador' 
    WHEN state = 'NT' THEN 'Northwest Territories' 
    WHEN state = 'NS' THEN 'Nova Scotia' 
    WHEN state = 'NU' THEN 'Nunavut' 
    WHEN state = 'ON' THEN 'Ontario' 
    WHEN state = 'PE' THEN 'Prince Edward Island' 
    WHEN state = 'QC' THEN 'Quebec' 
    WHEN state = 'SK' THEN 'Saskatchewan' 
    WHEN state = 'YT' THEN 'Yukon Territory' 
END AS state
FROM business

"""
result = spark.sql(query)
result.show()
```

This is what I end up with:

[image: 1]

But I'd like it to look like this, just with full state names instead of abbreviations:

[image: 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN state = 'AL' THEN 'Alabama' WHEN state = 'AK' THEN 'Alaska' WHEN state = 'AZ' THEN 'Arizona' WHEN state = 'AR' THEN 'Arkansas' WHEN state = 'CA' THEN 'California' WHEN state = 'CO' THEN 'Colorado' WHEN state = 'CT' THEN 'Connecticut' WHEN state = 'DE' THEN 'Delaware' WHEN state = 'DC' THEN 'District of Columbia' WHEN state = 'FL' THEN 'Florida' WHEN state = 'GA' THEN 'Georgia' WHEN state = 'HI' THEN 'Hawaii' WHEN state = 'ID' THEN 'Idaho' WHEN state = 'IL' THEN 'Illinois' WHEN state = 'IN' THEN 'Indiana' WHEN state = 'IA' THEN 'Iowa' WHEN state = 'KS' THEN 'Kansas' WHEN state = 'KY' THEN 'Kentucky' WHEN state = 'LA' THEN 'Louisiana' WHEN state = 'ME' THEN 'Maine' WHEN state = 'MD' THEN 'Maryland' WHEN state = 'MA' THEN 'Massachusetts' WHEN state = 'MI' THEN 'Michigan' WHEN state = 'MN' THEN 'Minnesota' WHEN state = 'MS' THEN 'Mississippi' WHEN state = 'MO' THEN 'Missouri' WHEN state = 'MT' THEN 'Montana' WHEN state = 'NE' THEN 'Nebraska' WHEN state = 'NV' THEN 'Nevada' WHEN state = 'NH' THEN 'New Hampshire' WHEN state = 'NJ' THEN 'New Jersey' WHEN state = 'NM' THEN 'New Mexico' WHEN state = 'NY' THEN 'New York' WHEN state = 'NC' THEN 'North Carolina' WHEN state = 'ND' THEN 'North Dakota' WHEN state = 'OH' THEN 'Ohio' WHEN state = 'OK' THEN 'Oklahoma' WHEN state = 'OR' THEN 'Oregon' WHEN state = 'PA' THEN 'Pennsylvania' WHEN state = 'RI' THEN 'Rhode Island' WHEN state = 'SC' THEN 'South Carolina' WHEN state = 'SD' THEN 'South Dakota' WHEN state = 'TN' THEN 'Tennessee' WHEN state = 'TX' THEN 'Texas' WHEN state = 'UT' THEN 'Utah' WHEN state = 'VT' THEN 'Vermont' WHEN state = 'VA' THEN 'Virginia' WHEN state = 'WA' THEN 'Washington' WHEN state = 'WV' THEN 'West Virginia' WHEN state = 'WI' THEN 'Wisconsin' WHEN state = 'WY' THEN 'Wyoming' WHEN state = 'AB' THEN 'Alberta' WHEN state = 'BC' THEN 'British Columbia' WHEN state = 'MB' THEN 'Manitoba' WHEN state = 'NM' THEN 'New Brunswick' WHEN state = 'NL' THEN 'Newfoundland and Labrador' WHEN state = 'NT' THEN 'Northwest Territories' WHEN state = 'NS' THEN 'Nova Scotia' WHEN state = 'NU' THEN 'Nunavut' WHEN state = 'ON' THEN 'Ontario' WHEN state = 'PE' THEN 'Prince Edward Island' WHEN state = 'QC' THEN 'Quebec' WHEN state = 'SK' THEN 'Saskatchewan' WHEN state = 'YT' THEN 'Yukon Territory' END AS state,
    COUNT(*)
    FROM business
    GROUP BY state
```